# How do I extract a substring from this string?

Tags: perl

I have a string that looks like: `/somedir/ref/some-dir/foo.word`

How could I extract `foo` from the above string? The whole string, including `foo` may vary, however, the structure is always the same. It will always the letters between the last slash and the last dot.

Comment: How is the structure "the same"? Do you need to capture the _letters_ between the _last slash_ and the _last dot_, or ..?

Comment: That is correct, always the letters between the last slash and the last dot.

Comment: Update your question with clarifications: don't hide those in the comments.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're trying to find the filename (without extension) from a fully-qualified file path. If this is the case, then look into the [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) core module:

```
my $str = "/somedir/ref/some-dir/foo.word";
my( $filename, $directory, $suffix ) = fileparse($str, qr/\.[^.]*/);
```

The `fileparse()` method takes two arguments: the string to be parsed and the file suffix to be removed. If you don't know what the file suffix is going to be beforehand, then you can supply a regular expression. In this case, the suffix will match a period followed by zero or more non-period characters.

**Edit:** And if you're not finding filenames, and want the letters between the last `/` and the last `.`, try this:

```
my $str = "/somedir/ref/some-dir/foo.word";
my @elems1 = split '/', $str;
my @elems2 = split '\.', $elems1[-1];
my $foo = $elems2[-2];
```

TIMTOWTDI! :-)

Comment: you may want to join all but the last element of `@elems2` rather than just getting the second to last.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s/.*\/([^.]*)\..*/$1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($str =~ /\/([^\/]+)\.[^\/]*?$/) {
    $foo = $1; # This is the word 'foo' in your test case.
} else {
    die("Error matching string");
}
```

Demonstration (using Ruby, but the regex is the same in both languages): http://www.rubular.com/r/7FUeFFV4QI

*Edit: Fixed a bug*

Comment: If $str doesn't match that regex, you'll be assigning to $foo whatever $1 was after the last successful regex match.

Comment: While you are certainly correct, does that truly merit a downvote?  Fixed in the post.

Comment: @Sean - This is not an issue at all, especially since we do not know the nature of the OPs problem. Perhaps it might even be DESIRABLE behavior, I know I've used a situation similar to this where I did in fact want the previous value when the current one failed. I have up-voted this for its wrongful down-vote. No valid answers/code should be down-voted IMHO.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer; it was just a side comment.  Are you the one who just went on a downvoting spree on a bunch of my old answers?

Comment: @Sean: I was not; my apologies for suspecting you.  I would never downvote legitimate answers out of revenge.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = '/somedir/ref/some-dir/foo.word';

if ( my ($x) = $s =~ m{/(\w+)\.\w+\z} ) {
    print "$x\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my ($foo) = $str =~ m|/(\w+)[^/]+$|;
```

That assumes the "foo" part can consist of any "word" characters (alphanumeric plus underscore).

Comment: I checked it before I posted it.  This command prints "foo": perl -le 'my $str = "/somedir/ref/some-dir/foo.word"; my ($foo) = $str =~ m|/(\w+)[^/]+$|; print $foo'

Comment: The word to be matched can be anything, so \w cannot match for example : `foo-bar`

Comment: bourbaki: No, the word to be matched can contain only letters, per the original poster's comment.

Comment: @foy: \w does exactly what I said it does: alphanumeric plus underscore.  I posted my answer before the OP clarified that only letters were allowed.

Comment: Why the hell are people still upvoting that "This is incorrect" comment?  My answer works perfectly on the original case, as I demonstrated.  If you somehow disagree, what's incorrect about it?  What output do you see?

Answer (score -1):

```
$str =~ m/\/(\w+)\./
```

foo will be stored in the special $1 variable in perl. 
If you want it in a normal variable after just assign it.

```
$myvar = $1;
```

This is easily the simplest solution listed so far.

This will extract any word string between "/" and "." in the input. It will always be the word you want, unless there is multiple periods in the string to match against. But I am assuming "." will only be at the end (like on a file extenstion).

Comment: Style improvement: Eliminate nugatory side effect variables and leaning toothpicks altogether. `my ($result) = $str =~ m{/(\w+)\.};`

Comment: Curious why someone would down-vote perfectly valid code that answers the question precisely.